# How do I get my nested getter to reference the correct property?

Tags: javascript, node.js, properties, getter

I have a class like the following.

```
class ColorTest {

    #light;

    constructor() {

        this.#light = {
            color: "Purple", 
            brightness: "Bright", 
        }
        this.colors = {
            first: {
                get color() {
                    return this.light.color;
                }, 
                get brightness() {
                    return this.light.brightness;
                }
            }, 
            second: {
                color: "", 
                brightness: ""
            }
        }
    }

    get light() { 
        return this.#light; 
    }
    set light(value) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}

let colorTest = ColorTest();
let firstColor = colorTest.colors.first.color;
```

When I try to run this code it gives me an error message that says *"TypeError: Cannot read property 'color' of undefined"*, with a reference to the line that says `return this.light.color;`. No matter what I try, I cannot figure out how to get around this. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's what I'm suspecting too. But how to I get a reference to the `this` of the class?

Comment: Why not simply do `this.colors = {first: this.light, second: {…}};`?

Comment: `this` inside the getter refers (usually) to the object it was accessed on, that is `colorTest.colors.first`. That object doesn't have a `.light` property. You can either add one (to reference `this.#light`), or not use `this`. Use the old [`const that = this;` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572). Or even easier, `const light = this.#light = {…};` and then refer to `light` directly.